# How to change gridview layout correctly while scrolling in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I have a gridview in my android project which show some Items that fetch from. I use a custom adapter extends BaseAdapter and a custom layout for my gridview to show each item.
What I need is to change the gridview custom layout when a button click, I use a FloatingActionButton that when I click on that the layout change correctly, but the problem is when I am scrolling the gridview and click the FAB the gridview layout change but it render incorrectly !!! 
What should I do to change layout correctly? Is there anyway to stop gridview from scrolling then change the layout?

P.S: I've used gridview.invalidate() method and some other methods like this but nothing works ! I also should mention that when the layout render incorrectly when I scroll up and down it became correct !

Answer (score 0):

This should be very possible and easy using android's recycle view with it's layout manager. check up on their documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Comment: thanks for your answer but I used gridview (inside a scrollview), I don't want to do change it from scratch ... (I also have header and footer for my gridview)

Comment: you might face a touch interception issue putting a gridview in a scrollview. but if you wish to continue with what's on ground, you might consider scrolling the list to the top once the layout is changed. in that way, it starts the re rendering every view from the begining

Comment: yes I resolve the interception issue, I want to be at the position where the gridview was, so It's not a solution to start from the beginning.